# Jenkins - git checkout deletes files

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkins pipeline:

```
node {
    dir('/my/dir'){
        stage 'checkout'
        git url: 'https://github.com/my/project.git'
    }
}
```

There were a few files in `/my/dir` which were deleted after this pipeline completed.

Is this due to `dir` or `git`?

Answer (score 3):

This was due to the `git` step since you tell the step to clone the repository into cwd which is `/my/dir/`, as part of this, git cleans the directory.